# Prove that $\frac{\partial P} {\partial y} =\frac{\partial Q} {\partial x} $, given $f(x,y) = P(x,y) \widehat i + Q(x,y) \widehat j$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given a two dimensional vector field $f(x,y) = P(x,y) \widehat i + Q(x,y) \widehat j$ where the partial derivatives are continuous on an open set. If $f$ is the gradient of some potential $\phi$, prove that $$\dfrac{\partial P} {\partial y} =\dfrac{\partial Q} {\partial x} $$

I am not sure how to go ahead with this problem. Could someone give me a direction on how to proceed ahead? Here are somethings which I tried :

$\nabla \phi = \dfrac { \partial \phi}{\partial x}  \widehat i + \dfrac { \partial \phi}{\partial y} \widehat j = f(x,y) = P(x,y) \widehat i + Q(x,y) \widehat j$ for some potential function $\phi$.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. You have $P = \phi_x$ and $Q = \phi_y$, so $P_y = \phi_{xy} = \phi_{yx} = Q_x$.

Comment: Got it. Finally :) Thanks again!